# Understanding iOS Crash Report via Test Flight

Tags: iphone, ios, stack-trace, testflight

I have begun testing my app via Test Flight and from time to time I get I receive this error: _sigtramp + 42. It only occurs at application launch and so far only on iOS 6.0. Has anyone else ran into this or can you help me located what is going wrong?

[image: Test Flight Stacktrace]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a .dsym file to your testflight build so that it can symbolicate the debug log.

1. Go to xcode's organizer
2. Select the Archives tab
3. Right click on the archive you used to upload the build to testflight
4. Select "Show in finder"
5. Right click on the .xarchive file and select "Show package contents"
6. Go to the dSYMs folder
7. Right click the .dSYM file and compress the file (zip it)
8. Drop that zip file into testflight under the Crashes tab where it says "Drop dSYM here"

Refresh the page, and hopefully the debug information will give you some more information as to what's happening.

Comment: You could also use the TestFlight app. That should automatically add the dSYM file when uploading to TestFlight, after archiving.

Comment: @Mikael Very true, but I'm assuming he wants to see the debug info for the build already on TestFlight. But ya definitely use that technique for future builds to save you time!

Comment: yes in this case it's definitely so that he miss the dSYM and should follow your instructions. Just wanted to put it out there :)

Comment: @Eric I should have mentioned I already uploaded the .dysm file. No more information was available.

Comment: @morcutt You may want to look into getting the full crash report from the device that experienced it. It could be that the crash is happening on a different thread other than the main one, but the main one is handling it.

Comment: @Eric I think that is the problem. This has occurred on my device yet it still produces nothing I have been able to trace at the time. Though, I have found some threads stating it has occurred when calling performSelector which I am doing in the delegate to multiple view controllers.

Comment: @morcutt Ya usually this error occurs when you are trying to call a method on a released object. Make sure your viewcontroller exists before calling performSelector. Use the call [yourVC respondsToSelector:@selector(theMethod)] before actually making the call. That should hopefully solve your problems